# Loading raster to PostGIS using QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, raster

I am having trouble loading a raster (.asc) file to PostGIS 2.0.1 using the plugin Database - PostGIS Raster - Load raster to postgis in QGIS 1.8.0 on Win Vista 64 bit. I get the following error message:

---

> Ett fel har inträffat vid Pythonexekvering:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/Magnus/.qgis//python/plugins\wktraster\DlgRasterLoader.py",
> line 126, in browseRaster
> self.getMetadata(str(fileName))   File "C:/Users/Magnus/.qgis//python/plugins\wktraster\DlgRasterLoader.py",
> line 163, in getMetadata
> ds=gdal.Open(filename) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Open'
>
> Python version:
> 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
>
> QGIS version:
> 1.8.0-Lisboa Lisboa, 6416f38
>
> Python sökväg: ['C:/Users/Magnus/.qgis//python/plugins\sextante',
> 'C:/PROGRA~2/GIS/QGIS/apps/qgis/./python',
> 'C:/Users/Magnus/.qgis//python',
> 'C:/Users/Magnus/.qgis//python/plugins',
> 'C:/PROGRA~2/GIS/QGIS/apps/qgis/./python/plugins',
> 'C:\PROGRA~2\GIS\QGIS\bin\python27.zip',
> 'C:\PROGRA~2\GIS\QGIS\apps\Python27\DLLs',
> 'C:\PROGRA~2\GIS\QGIS\apps\Python27\lib',
> 'C:\PROGRA~2\GIS\QGIS\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win',
> 'C:\PROGRA~2\GIS\QGIS\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk',
> 'C:\PROGRA~2\GIS\QGIS\apps\qgis\bin',
> 'C:\PROGRA~2\GIS\QGIS\apps\Python27',
> 'C:\PROGRA~2\GIS\QGIS\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages',
> 'C:\PROGRA~2\GIS\QGIS\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL',
> 'C:\PROGRA~2\GIS\QGIS\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32',
> 'C:\PROGRA~2\GIS\QGIS\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
> 'C:\PROGRA~2\GIS\QGIS\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin',
> 'C:\PROGRA~2\GIS\QGIS\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode',
> 'C:\Users\Magnus\.qgis\python\plugins\mmqgis/forms',
> 'C:\PROGRA~2\GIS\QGIS\apps\qgis\python\plugins\fTools\tools']

QGIS opens the file just fine.

Any suggestions on what to do?

Answer (score 2):

I have two hypothesis:
 1) It seems that there is a problem with your PYTHON_PATH environmental variable. The variable used to tell Python where the installed modules and libraries are. I think you have to define an environmental variable pointing to that path. 
 2) It could be also that you have not installed the GDAL wrapper. Try to import it in a standard python console (using: import osgeo.gdal) if some error happens it means that you need to install gdal python wrappers.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I didn´t manage to solve this using QGIS, so I used FME instead.